# How to asynchronously load CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so how can I use loadCSS (https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/README.md) to allow the browser to asynchronously load CSS and JavaScript?

I have this in my head tag:

```
<link rel="preload" href="http://zoidstudios.com/assets/css/main.css" as="style" onload="this.rel='stylesheet">
<noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://zoidstudios.com/assets/css/main.css"></noscript>
```

And this at the bottom of my html file :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/eb515f50a5.js"></script>
<script src="http://zoidstudios.com/assets/js/functions.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://zoidstudios.com/assets/js/loadcss.min.js"></script>

<script>
    loadCSS( "http://zoidstudios.com/assets/css/main.css" );
</script>
```

Comment: What goes wrong when you try the code you posted? Are you asking us to interpret for you the documentation you linked?

Comment: I am asking if this is correct because when i run my site through Google's pagespeed insights tester it says all of my js & css are delaying page load. It's saying this even with the above included in my html file. @this-vidor

Comment: lokos like you did it in a wrong way.. the noscript tag should hopefully not be part of the head

Comment: So should the noscript tag be in the body or? @Wolfgang

Comment: Warning: It looks like you haven't closed the single-quoted string in the `onload` attribute of the first `<link>` tag.

Comment: fixed that before and well still hasnt helped? @this-vidor

Comment: Keep `<link` in `noscript` only and add `async="async"` to all scripts except `jquery.min.js`. Load `loadcss.min.js` with `$.getScript` and run `loadCSS` from its `success`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into loaders like [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/)? Most loaders will support CSS natively and/or offer CSS plugins to load CSS, JS, etc. asynchronously all while ensuring dependencies. If you have many files to load I would suggest looking into a loader of your preference.

Comment: RequireJS, and others, are not bundlers (although most offer optimization and/or bundling tools like r.js for example) they are AMD loaders. "The Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) API specifies a mechanism for defining modules such that the module and its dependencies can be asynchronously loaded". https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD

Comment: If you edit your answer with those other suggestions I can remove the down-vote. However, OP has clearly already found such a loader.

Comment: Still don't know what to do @JesseJohnson

Comment: For example with RequireJS you would include requirejs.js and the requirejs/text plugin (other plugins exists for loading CSS but this is one of the most popular). Once you define your dependencies within the config file you will be free to asynchronously load your CSS, and other resources, without having to worry about the order in which they load. Here is a link to walk through setting up RequireJS with CSS loading: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.0/Subsystems/Extensions/Content/extensions-load-resources.htm

Comment: downvote comment: you added your comment as an answer and it's not

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the CSS. If PageSpeed thinks your page load is bogged down, it's probably the result of all those `<script>` tags at the end of your `<body>` tag. Just because they are placed in the body tag does not mean they are asynchronous.

You can leave them all in the `<head>` tag. You can include the attribute `async` or `defer` to get asynchronous loading: have a look at [this explanation](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html).

So, something like this should do:

```
<script
    src="http://zoidstudios.com/assets/js/functions.min.js"
    defer>
</script>
```

Note that if any of those scripts expect the DOM to be parsed (i.e., they expect certain elements to exist already), you should use `defer` instead of `async`, as explained in the linked article. Or, you can leave those in the `<body>` tag, and use `async`.

#### Update

If my hypothesis is correct (that PageSpeed does not support `rel='preload'` on `<link>` tags), notice that the documentation linked in your question [advises you to](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/README.md#recommended-usage-pattern)

> include the loadCSS script, as well as the loadCSS rel=preload
>   polyfill script in your page (inline to run right away, or in an
>   external file if the CSS is low-priority)

You may be able to eliminate the final warning by using the recommended polyfill.

The general problem, "how do I load CSS asynchronously?" [has been asked and answered many times on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asynchronously+load+css), as I'm sure you know!

Comment: It says CSS and JavaScipt. If i do this it just says CSS. @this-vidor

Comment: P.S. Just because Google warns you that you are synchronously loading resources doesn't mean that your page is actually slow.

Comment: I know but it doesn't hurt to have an even faster page. Ill just inline the critical css from now :D Cheers!

Comment: @Zoid Like you said, it doesn't hurt. You can leave your code as-is, and just accept that Google may raise a warning that doesn't impact real users.

Comment: @Zoid Updated the answer with a final suggestion.